# Why i am running out of memory when my web api is loading 30000+ records? coding in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, out-of-memory

I want to ask why i am running out of memeory when my web api is loading 30000+ records, I have used `connection.Open();` and `connection.Close();` to open and close the function and i am using xml format in the web api, Am i coding it wrong with my code or is it really about my computer ram memory?

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpGet()]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<UserClass> user = new List<UserClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    user.Add(new UserClass()
                    {
                        UserId = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                        Name = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        Mobile = sdr.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        Age = Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(3)),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr.GetValue(4))
                    });
                }
            sqlconn.Close();
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

class:

```
public class TestClass
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

It is not about the service said `OutOfMemoryExepection`, it is my google chrome out of memory when i am testing my code, i have get function with all records and i have get function with search userid and name, and i have 30000+ records to read which is from my sql server database. When records read over 10000+, google chrome will start out of memory. I don't know what i have written my code wrong or my computer doesn't have enough memory to run the code in xml format. I want to know is about my code have issue to make google chrome out of memory or my computer doesn't have enough ram memory to run the code. It show `Error code: Out Of Memory` in google chrome when i am running the code.

The situation which i had when i am try to read the code

the link: `http://localhost:{myip}/api/user`

[image]

Comment: I see you are adding records into "user" collection but returning "draft"! What is draft here in this case?
Check your exception message, stack traces, and inner exceptions if applicable then it should give you some hint where this occurred!

Comment: @Nirmal Subedi Sorry, i wrote it wrong when i writing this question, I will edit now

Comment: You should be aware that your data reader has `GetString`, `GetInt32` and `GetDateTime` methods.

Comment: At which point EXACTLY does an `OutOfMemoryException` get thrown?

Comment: You should be creating your connection, command and data reader with `using` statements, so explicitly closing the connection should not be required.

Comment: @John it shows Out of Memory in google chrome when i am testing the code. I should use the `using` statement, so i don't need to close the connection, because the `using` statement will close the connection automatically. Is it right?

Comment: So it's not your service that is running out of memory but the client browser? We shouldn't need to ask this stuff. You should provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation in the first place.

Comment: In my opinion it's not useful to return all 300000 records to the front. You could use pagination to solve the issue.

Comment: Agreed, 300k rows in a browser page is absurd.

Comment: `Pagination` will it affect to call the api function? like i will use this web api to call from the cloud server, i want to know will it affect in call function

Comment: You need to describe clearly what is "google chrome will start out of memory". The exact error message, the screen shots and anything else useful to help others understand your situation, when the backend is not actually experiencing a problem.

Comment: It show `Error code: Out Of Memory` in google chrome when i am running the code

Comment: When searching the internet for "google chrome out of memory" I get a lot results which offer solutions. Did you try any of them?

Comment: @SirRufo is it work for web api, if it does, i would like to have a try please

Comment: @LexLi I have updated a screenshot for the situation i have when i running those 30000+ records.

Comment: Then all previous discussions are less helpful at this moment, as you should start from the browser side, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: Just update your SQL Query to return like 10 records:
string sqlquery = "SELECT top 10 UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";

Seems your browser is blown away because you are returning very large results. If this works, then you really need to update your API to implement pagination as others suggested above.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi I think I need to pagination to get the result, because i used`select top 10 UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser` and it works, but does pagination affect calling the api from cloud server?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not userfull to pass all data to the front. So, I recommend you to use pagination. For example you could define the following class:

```cs
public class Page<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _data;

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Data => _data;

    public Page()
    {
        _data = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item) => _data.Add(item);
}
```

Then it's possible to pass partial data to the front using the class:

```cs
private const string QUERY = @"
    select
        [UserID],
        [Name],
        [Mobile],
        [Age],
        [Date]
    from tbluser
    order by UserID
    offset @offset rows fetch next @limit rows only;
    select @total = count(*) from tbluser;
";

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] int pageIndex = 1,
                                     [FromQuery] int pageSize = 100,
                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var users = new Page<User>();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(QUERY, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@limit", pageSize);
        SqlParameter total = command.Parameters.Add("@total", SqlDbType.Int);
        total.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                users.Add(new User()
                {
                    UserId = reader.GetString(0),
                    Name = reader.GetString(1),
                    Mobile = reader.GetString(2),
                    Age = reader.GetInt32(3),
                    Date = reader.GetDateTime(4)
                });
            }
        }
        await connection.CloseAsync();
        users.Index = pageIndex;
        users.Total = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(int)total.Value / pageSize);
    }
    return Ok(users);
}
```

You also need to understand following:

1. `OFFSET`/`FETCH` have some [usage features](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned).
2. It's not good idea to implement data access layer within controller.

Next implement client's script, that displays rows from the `Data` property and uses page `Index` and `Total` properties for navigation.