# Out of memory in Client Web browser but server is ok

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, out-of-memory

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application in a Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2016. Everything works fine when users list less than 30000 records in the system, but when they want more records, the browser (chrome or edge) show the Out of Memory error, but the server memory is ok and so is the memory of the user pc.

This used to work fine in the old datacenter but when I changed the server, this error now appears with large data.

Is something related to IIS? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356569/why-i-am-running-out-of-memory-when-my-web-api-is-loading-30000-records-coding

Comment: 30k records is *a lot* to send to a browser. Remember that it needs to hold both the json and the objects created from that json. Plus the HTML generated to display those objects

Comment: There are many reasons for out of memory error,  especially if you are running the websites on a 32 bit server, In 32 bit, your worker process is limited to 2 GB of virtual memory, you can try to switch to 64 bit.